# Paypal - Transaction id idenitication

Tags: paypal

I am a merchant and provide ebooks download after the payment is completed from customer through paypal. After the paypal transaction is completed, I will obtained the unique transaction ID from paypal and then stored in my DataBase. Then, the customer can download the ebook if the transaction id is found in my DB so I need to verify the transaction id is come from paypal instead of hacker or fraud. Any API to do that? My site is using php.

Comment: If you're talking about IPN, the verification process is completely documented. If you're talking about some other PayPal API, you only need to make sure you're actually talking to a PayPal server.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. You mentioned is happened during in the transaction process but my concern is after the transaction is completed because the hacker may insert some illegal transaction id into my own DB. So, I needed to verify the transaction id before the customer access the digital goods. Please help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe what will help you here is the PDT (Payment Data Transfer), when a customer pays you, PayPal sends the transaction ID of the payment to you by appending the transaction ID to a URL you specify in your account Profile. This information is sent via a HTTP GET as this name/value pair:

tx=transactionID

After you get the transaction ID, you post a FORM to PayPal that includes the transaction ID and your identity token, a string value that identifies your account to PayPal. There are instructions below that describe how to get your identity token. The form looks like this:

```
<form method=post action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"> 
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_notify-synch"> 
<input type="hidden" name="tx" value="TransactionID"> 
<input type="hidden" name="at" value="YourIdentityToken"> 
<input type="submit" value="PDT"> 
</form>
```

now after that you receive the response from paypal to that request indicating that this is a correct transaction in paypal (HTTP Header has been omitted):

```
SUCCESS 
first_name=Jane+Doe 
last_name=Smith 
payment_status=Completed 
payer_email=janedoesmith%40hotmail.com 
payment_gross=3.99 
mc_currency=USD 
custom=For+the+purchase+of+the+rare+book+Green+Eggs+%26+Ham
```

Of course all this depends that you need to have PDT turned on in your paypal merchant account.

If you need more help refer to this link: [Paypal Payment Data Transfer](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/)

Comment: I am using PDT already. Let me try this method and I will ask again in here if encounter any problem. Thanks!

Comment: The best way to verify the Payments is via the use of IPN where you can post the transaction data back to PayPal and receive "Invalid" or "verified" status from PayPal . If you don't use the IPN , you can make use of the GetTransactionDetails API where you can fetch all the transaction related information from the PayPal and valid it by looking at the transaction details . You can refer the below link :https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/